# Have I lost all my Bitcoin, having sent them to a Bitcoin Cash wallet?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-cash, recover-private-key

I made a pretty big mistake of sending my Bitcoin that I had on Coinbase to a Bitcoin Cash wallet that I own on my Exodus wallet instead of the Bitcoin wallet. I can see on Coinbase that the address it went to is the Coinbase Cash wallet that I have on Exodus and the transaction has now been completed, but nothing appears in Exodus.

I understand that sometimes this can be ok depending on the address format and I'm not entirely sure how long it is supposed to take until you see it. Do I take it that I've just lost all those coins since they haven't appeared at all? Also if so where do those coins go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keys are interchangeable on both chains. If you export the private key of the address you sent it to on the bitcoin cash wallet , and import it back into another wallet (Exodus for Bitcoin?) , you should see your bitcoins.

Comment: I would upvote your answer if you would elaborate a bit on the "import it back" part of your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Bobo is correct

The private key on Bitcoin Cash is identical to the private key on Bitcoin.

So, just import the seed phrase from your Bitcoin Cash wallet into a Bitcoin wallet.  Your funds will be there

If there is a address compatibility issue, just use a different wallet, such as Coinomi, it has good compatibility

Comment: I must not be understanding this, because it sounds like  a way to get infinitely rich.  I have some Bitcoin Cash with private key "A".  I send it to a different Bitcoin Cash address with private key "B".  I import the key "B" into a Bitcoin wallet and claim the BItcoins.  Then I send my Bitcoin Cash to a new Bitcoin Cash address with private key "C".  Then I import the key "C" into a Bitcoin wallet and claim the Bitcoins.  Repeat forever.  What have I thoroughly misunderstood here?

Comment: The coins never leave the chain, the keys are just the same.  So, if you send the coins (on Bitcoin) to a Bitcoin Cash address, you have really just used an identical Bitcoin address which you now also control, since your Bitcoin Cash seed phrase can be used on Bitcoin.  Bitcoin uses the same key infrastructure, so you can control any Bitcoin addresses you have BCH keys for. Ordinarily this is useless, but in this case it can recover the funds